# Is it possible to add a "refresh" button in excel to start a python program on Mac?

Tags: python, excel

is it possible to add a "refresh" button in Excel (on MacOS) to start a Python program, which loads data into this excel sheet?

Comment: The excel file will be open, so the external python script won't be able to write data on that file. Why do you want to use an external python script when you have Macros integrated in Excel?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the python script could close the excel, load the data and open it again tho

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think we will do it in VBA.